# Complexity of the algorithm with known complexity of the subtasks

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science

The input of a dynamic programming algorithm is a single, n long
sequence. The algorithm considers all possible substrings of the sequence, and for the k long substring, it calculates a value in O(k) time.

I was wondering if someone tell me how can I estimate the running time of this algorithm.

Comment: Maybe this question will be better suited in the Computer Science site: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could is simply be o(n!)?

Comment: # of for loops?

Comment: @Djee did you mean `O(n!)`? Yes, it could, but there is a better approx - `O(n^3)`. The prove can be found below.

Comment: On [so] we mark good answers by upvoting them, and the one which answers the question gets a solution mark additionally.  I strongly recommend [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's dig in.

```
7     abcdefg
6     abcdef
6      bcdefg
5     abcde
5      bcdef
5       cdefg
.
.
.
```

OK, so for a string of length `n`, we have `2` substrings of length `n-1`, `3` of length `n-2`, ... , `n` of length `1`.

[image]